# ¿Cómo guardar el contenido de varios inputs en una variable?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

os comento, me encuentro realizando una aplicación con Javascript, HTML y CSS, que se trata de completar correctamente unos huecos (los inputs) y me ha surgido un problema que no consigo resolver. Dispongo de un texto con varios inputs (distinto número de inputs en función del texto), y la intención es guardar el contenido de estos inputs en una lista. Os pongo un ejemplo de texto:

El perro @ tiene hambre @ pero no hay comida en casa @

Las "@" correspondería con los inputs. Lo que busco es guardar el contenido de los inputs en una lista y en el orden correcto. Es decir, el contenido del primer input, sería el primer elemento de la lista, el segundo input con el segundo de la lista, y así sucesivamente, independientemente de que input se rellene antes.

Dispongo del siguiente código:

```js
function mostrarEjercicio(textoEjercicio){
  $('#mostrarTextoAlumno').remove();
  
    var text=textoEjercicio;
    var textSeparado=textoEjercicio.split("@");
    var nInput=textSeparado.length-1;
    var idInput=0;
    for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      if(text.charAt(i)=="@"){
        var inputN='<input id="'+idInput+'" type="text" style="width:55px; color:black">'
        text = text.replace("@", inputN);
        idInput++;
      }
    }
    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTextoAlumno"><div class="box-blue" ><h4 >'+ text + '</h4></div>';
    cadena=cadena+'<div align="center" id="mostrarSolucion"><button style="color:white" type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalInstruccionesAlumno">Instrucciones</button>'
    cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="verBorradorBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Ver borrador</button></div></div>';
    $('#texto').append(cadena);

    var respuestaAlumno=[];

    $('#verBorradorBtn').on('click',function(){

      respuestaAlumno[i]=$("#"+i+"").val();

    });
 
}

mostrarEjercicio('El perro @ tiene hambre @ pero no hay comida en casa @');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="bg">
     <div class="container text-center">
      <div id="logoInicio">
      </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
       <div id="datos">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div id="texto"> 
       </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
       <div id="informacion">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

La parte que no conozco sería a partir `$('#verBorradorBtn').on('click',function()` que es cuando almacenaría esa información de los inputs.Otra parte que no conozco, es como hacer referencia al id de forma correcta `respuestaAlumno[i]=$("#"+i+"").val();`,

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el HTML? Es mucho más sencillo trabajar en un problema si podemos reproducir el escenario

Comment: Voy a ver que puedo subir que pueda servir, porque son bastantes líneas, y depende de varios archivos. Gracias por cierto por preocuparse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pues creo que lo tienes ya casi hecho: te falta tomar la respuesta y mostrarla en algún sitio:

```js
function mostrarEjercicio(textoEjercicio){
  $('#mostrarTextoAlumno').remove();
  
    var text=textoEjercicio;
    var textSeparado=textoEjercicio.split("@");
    var nInput=textSeparado.length-1;
    var idInput=0;
    for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      if(text.charAt(i)=="@"){
        var inputN='<input id="'+idInput+'" type="text" style="width:55px; color:black">'
        text = text.replace("@", inputN);
        idInput++;
      }
    }
    var cadena = '<div id="mostrarTextoAlumno"><div class="box-blue" ><h4 >'+ text + '</h4></div>';
    cadena=cadena+'<div align="center" id="mostrarSolucion"><button style="color:white" type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalInstruccionesAlumno">Instrucciones</button>'
    cadena=cadena+'<button type="button" id="verBorradorBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Ver borrador</button></div></div>';
    $('#texto').append(cadena);

    var respuestaAlumno=[];

    $('#verBorradorBtn').on('click',function(){
      for (let i=0; i<idInput;i++) {
        respuestaAlumno.push($(`#${i}`).val());
      }
      console.log('Los valores son',respuestaAlumno.toString());
      mostrarInfo(respuestaAlumno);

    });
 
}

function mostrarInfo(valores) {
   const info= $('#informacion');
   let lista=$('<ol></ol>');
   valores.forEach(value => lista.append(`<li>${value}</li>`));
   info.append(lista);
}   

mostrarEjercicio('El perro @ tiene hambre @ pero no hay comida en casa @');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div class="bg">
     <div class="container text-center">
      <div id="logoInicio">
      </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
       <div id="datos">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div id="texto"> 
       </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="row">
       <div id="informacion">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Exacto, así es, muchísimas gracias por la ayuda!